# Constructor injection - is it ok to use new null-object if none provided in the constructor?

Tags: php, language-agnostic, dependency-injection

Imagine I have a bunch of classes, that can do logging, so I've created a logger interface and a couple of implementations (writing to file, to stdout, to db, etc.), but sometimes I don't care about logging those messages, so I've made an implementation, that simply ignores all of the messages.

Now this helps to avoid `if`s and just use `$this->logger->write($message)`, but I still have to inject the dummy logger every time.

So would it do any harm to do stuff like: `$this->logger = $logger ? $logger : new DummyLogger()` in the constructor.

I generally do no work in the constructor, but this kind of stuff doesn't seem too dangerous.

Would you choose this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before answering your question, I'd suggest to rethink your Logger architecture. Logging is always the same. You write a message to somewhere. The only thing that differs is the *somewhere* part, so it makes sense to separate your Logger into a generic Logger and various Writers. That allows for greater flexibility, for instance, you can use the Composite pattern to write to multiple Loggers at once.

Regarding your question: in general you want to avoid hardcoding dependencies into your code because it will directly impact on testability and reusability, e.g. your Logger can only be used with this particular NullWriter then. If you are going to distribute the Logger you will also have to distribute the Writer as well.

However, assuming that you would only distribute the Logger with the entire package of Writers anyway and you also provide the means to do ctor injection, I dont see much of an issue. You can still swap out the Writer if needed, so all is well.

It's somewhat different when we are talking about interpackage dependencies. You will want to avoid these, e.g. your classes in the Database package should not depend on classes in the Logger package.

An alternative to assigning the NullWriter from inside the Logger would be to use a LoggerFactory that creates the Logger and a specified Writer, injects the Writer and returns the Logger.

Comment: Your suggestion on the architecture makes sense, I'd just argue that I can still use the Composite pattern if I leave loggers the way they are.

Comment: @Fluffy yes, probably. I'm assuming your Loggers are effectively Writers in your code. But semantically it makes more sense to call them what they are.

Answer (score 1):

I would not choose that approach because it is a hard dependancy and an extra class. There are patterns to avoid these problems - and solving your dilemma.

You could implement a version of the observer pattern, something like:

```
class Loggable
{
    protected $aLoggers = array();

    public function addLogger(Logger $oLog) {
        $this->aLoggers[] = $oLog;
    }

    public function invokeLoggers($sMessage) {
        foreach($this->aLoggers as $oLog) {
            $oLog->write($sMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

These functions should ofcourse be in a seperate class so that any class using loggers can extend this functionality. You can now choose to not add loggers and thus the invoke will do nothing - or to not extend your original class at all.

```
class SomeClass extends Loggable
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        // Some code
        $this->invokeLoggers();
    }
}

$oSomeClass = new SomeClass();
$oSomeClass->addLogger(new FileLogger());
$oSomeClass->addLogger(new DatabaseLogger());
$oSomeClass->addLogger(new EmailLogger());
$oSomeClass->doSomething();
```

Comment: From my perspective, this will mean adding boilerplate code to every loggable class (pretty much what you have given), which is bad, because it's code duplication among all the loggable's and mixing of responsibilities. Should I require multiple logging destinations I'd rather create a `composite` patternish logger and not have to change any of the classes that do logging. And still I want only one logger for the time being, your solution will be replaced by a logger property + `if`, which I have tried to avoid originally. *tl;dr: I don't like this solution*

Comment: As my example shows the boilerplate code is added in a sepate class that you can easily use anywhere. In PHP5.4 you could even use a trait to include this functionality.

Comment: That would indeed make this solution more difficult if not impossible to implement without a application-redesign.